# $ (x^2+xy^4)dx+ 2y^3dy=0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that $ {e^x}^2 $ is an integrating factor of the equation

$$ (x^2+xy^4)dx+ 2y^3dy=0 $$

and hence solve it.

I have tried to solve the equation, however, I am getting the $ e^{2x^2} $ as the integrating factor. What have I done wrong?

[image]

Comment: isn't $N = 2y^3$? You used $N=y^3$.

Comment: @AnmolAgarwal Ya... Right. Thanks!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x^2+xy^4)dx+ 2y^3dy=0$$
$$x^2dx+(xy^4dx+ 2y^3dy)=0$$
$$x^2dx+\frac 12(2xy^4dx+ 4y^3dy)=0$$
$$x^2dx+\frac 12(y^4dx^2+ dy^4)=0$$
Integrating factor $\mu =e^{x^2}$
$$x^2e^{x^2}dx+\frac 12(e^{x^2}y^4dx^2+ e^{x^2}dy^4)=0$$
$$x^2e^{x^2}dx+\frac 12(de^{x^2}y^4)=0$$
Integrate:
$$\int x^2e^{x^2}dx+\frac 12e^{x^2}y^4=C$$
You have an error function for the integral.

Comment: Can you please tell why is my solution incorrect for this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3489080/394202

Comment: Yes will check your attempt @Soumee But I tried to solve it with exactness and whatever you try I think it can't be solved that way easily

Answer (score 1):

Since $N=2y^3$, we have

$$\frac{\large{\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}}{N}=\frac{4xy^3-0}{2y^3}=2x$$

therefore the integrating factor is

$$\text{IF}=\large{e^{\int f(x)\,dx}}=\large{e^{\int 2x\,dx}}=\large{e^{x^2}}$$