# Solve: $ (y^2+ 2x^2y)dx + (2x^3 - xy)dy = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve:

$$ (y^2+ 2x^2y)dx + (2x^3 - xy)dy = 0 $$

I tried to solve the differential equation in the following manner, but I am unable to arrive at the correct solution. The correct solution is:

$$ 4(xy)^{\frac{1}{3}} - \frac{2}{3}(x/y)^{\frac{3}{2}} = C $$

Please help me identify my mistake in the solution.

[image]

[image]

RECTIFICATION:

[image]

[image]

Comment: solved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588586/solve-y22x2ydx2x3-xydy-0

Comment: I don't know if that helps but you calculated IF to be $1/2xy^2$, but then you multiplied the DE by $1/2xy$.

Comment: Your integrating factor works fine Soumee

Answer (score 1):

$$(y^2+2x^2y)dx+(2x^3−xy)dy=0$$
$$(y+2x^2)ydx+(2x^2−y)xdy=0$$
Is not of the form 
$$f_1(xy)ydx+f_2(xy)xdy=0$$
So you can't use that method for this DE

Be carefull Soumee. $(y+2x^2)$ is a function $f(x,y)$ But it's not a function of the form $f(xy)$

---

**Edit**

The integrating factor $\mu(x,y)=x^{-5/2}y^{-1/2}$ proposed by @Soumee:
$$y(ydx-xdy)+2x^2dxy=0$$
Multiply by IF $x^{-5/2}y^{-1/2}$
$$x^{-5/2}y^{-1/2}y(ydx-xdy)+2x^{-5/2}y^{-1/2}x^2dxy=0$$
$$-x^{-1/2}y^{1/2}d\frac {y}{x}+2x^{-1/2}y^{-1/2}dxy=0$$
$$-\left (\frac {y}{x} \right )^{1/2}d\left (\frac {y}{x} \right )+2(xy)^{-1/2}d(xy)=0$$
Integrate

Comment: So, when the differential equation consists of terms of the form$ (xy)^k $ then only the DE can be solved using the method I have used?

Comment: Soumee a function of $xy$ can be any function that content $xy$. For exampes $\sin(xy)$ is a function of $xy.$ Or another example is  $ e^{3xy}$ You see what I mean ? @Soumee

Comment: Yes, I get it ..

Comment: @Soumee good. Now I think this DE can't be solved easily with exactness. The link provided in the comments gives you different methods for solving this DE

Comment: I think integrating factor can be assumed as $ x^h y^k $ and then be solved.

Comment: I got $h = \frac {-5}{2}$ and $ k = \frac{-1}{2} $. Wait, I am uploading the answer.

Comment: Ok I will look at it @Soumee

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: I have uploaded the complete solution. However, there is just a small mistake.

Comment: I think it's correct now I updated my answer @soumee

Comment: @Soumee your integrating factor works fine.

Comment: But the problem is $ 4(xy)^{\frac{1}{3}} - \frac{2}{3}(x/y)^{\frac{3}{2}} = C $ is the answer. However, I have got $4(xy)^{\frac{1}{3}} - \frac{2}{3}(y/x)^{\frac{3}{2}} = C$ as the answer.

Comment: the first exponent is $1/2$ not $1/3$ In the comment in the link provided the answer given by user is the same answer as yours. @Soumee are you talking aboutanother answer provided by your book ?

Comment: Sorry, I got $ 4(xy)^{\frac{1}{2}} - \frac{2}{3}(y/x)^{\frac{3}{2}} = C $ as the answer. Therefore now both the terms are incorrect! :(

Comment: Did you check the link provided in the comments ? The answer given by use is the same as yours @soumee

Comment: Oh! yes, user170231 has the same answer as mine. What answer are you getting?

Comment: Same answer as yours @Soumee with $1/2$ for the first exponent

Comment: Thank you for your help. Then could the answer given in the text be wrong?

Comment: YW @Soumee Sometimes it happens that answers provided in textbooks are wrong. The most important is that you know how to apply the methods

Comment: Yes, true. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution:
$$(y^2+ 2x^2y)dx + (2x^3 - xy)dy = 0$$
$$y(ydx-xdy)+ 2x^2(xdy +ydx) = 0$$
$$-y d\left ( \frac {y}x \right )+ 2d(xy) = 0$$
$$-\sqrt y d\left ( \frac {y}x \right )+ \frac 2 {\sqrt y}d(xy) = 0$$
An obvious integrating factor is $\mu(x)=1/\sqrt x$
$$-\sqrt {\frac y x} d\left ( \frac {y}x \right )+ \frac 2 {\sqrt {xy}}d(xy) = 0$$
It's integrable.
$$\frac 13 \left ( {\frac y x} \right)^{\frac 32}-2 {\sqrt {xy}} = C$$